# Jquery conflict in using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, slider, accordion

I have a parent html page whicg includes accordian JS file for my vertical menu. Also I want to include a simple image slide show , JS file in it. In order to avoid the jQuery conflict by including two JS files. I have used I `<frame>` tag . Its works fine in all modern browsers perfectly. But in Internet Explorer 6. My image slide show doesn't work at all.
here's my code.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //slides the element with class "menu_body" when paragraph with class "menu_head" is clicked 
    $("#firstpane p.menu_head").click(function()
    {
        $(this).css({backgroundImage:"url()"}).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).siblings().css({backgroundImage:"url()"});
    });

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

}
.menu_list {    
    width:100%
}
.menu_head {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin:1px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #fff url(left.png) center right no-repeat;
}
.menu_body {
    display:none;

}
.menu_body p{
  display:block;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin-top:0px;
  padding-left:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.menu_body a:hover{
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration:underline;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               <tr >
                    <td ><iframe src="simple_gallery.html" width="300px" height="250px" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="No"></iframe></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
               <div id="firstpane" class="menu_list"> <!--Code for menu starts here-->
        <p class="menu_head">Header-1</p>
        <div class="menu_body">
        <a href="#">Link-1</a>
         <a href="#">Link-2</a>
         <a href="#">Link-3</a> 
        </div>
        <p class="menu_head">Header-2</p>
        <div class="menu_body">
            <a href="#">Link-1</a>
         <a href="#">Link-2</a>
         <a href="#">Link-3</a> 
        </div>
        <p class="menu_head">Header-3</p>
        <div class="menu_body">
          <a href="#">Link-1</a>
         <a href="#">Link-2</a>
         <a href="#">Link-3</a>         
       </div>
  </div>
```

iframe link page contents :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/simple_slider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/simplegallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mygallery=new simpleGallery({
    wrapperid: "simplegallery1", //ID of main gallery container,
    dimensions: [300,250], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of the images exactly
    imagearray: [
        ["images/img-2.jpg", "#", "_new", "There's nothing like a nice swim in the Summer."],
        ["images/img-1.jpg", "#", "", ""],
        ["images/r-tata.jpg", "", "", "Eat your fruits, it's good for you!"],
        ["images/inside-image1.jpg", "", "", ""]
    ],
    autoplay: [true, 2500, 5], //[auto_play_boolean, delay_btw_slide_millisec, cycles_before_stopping_int]
    persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    oninit:function(){ //event that fires when gallery has initialized/ ready to run
        //Keyword "this": references current gallery instance (ie: try this.navigate("play/pause"))
    },
    onslide:function(curslide, i){ //event that fires after each slide is shown
        //Keyword "this": references current gallery instance
        //curslide: returns DOM reference to current slide's DIV (ie: try alert(curslide.innerHTML)
        //i: integer reflecting current image within collection being shown (0=1st image, 1=2nd etc)
    }
})
</script>
<style type="text/css">

}
.menu_list {    
    width:100%
}
.menu_head {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin:1px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #fff url(left.png) center right no-repeat;
}
.menu_body {
    display:none;

}
.menu_body p{
  display:block;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin-top:0px;
  padding-left:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.menu_body a:hover{
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration:underline;
  }
</style>
<div id="simplegallery1"></div>
```

Comment: Did you test to check if your slideshow plugin is compatible with IE6?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I checked it was working in IE 6 with ease.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté before I used it my code I checked both the jquery for IE 6 compatibility.

Comment: So the plugin runs fine on the demo page in IE6? Weird, I still test my stuff on IE6 as well, but honestly, seeing as IE6 takes less than 2% of the global browsers share, I wouldn't worry too much about it. You could maybe link to which plugin you're using, so people may be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a iFrame to stop a jQuery conflict can't you just use [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) with jquery? Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: do you think it i'll solve the problem ...??...and will IE 6 support this jquery noconflict perfectly.....??

Comment: Yes IE6 supports the noconflict method. But with IE6 now being 0.2% of the target market with latest browser stats I'm kinda hoping that a lot of sites drop IE6 support so we no longer need to keep working with them and people upgrade :)